# Android - How to combine rows based on duplicate data in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, sum, rows, duplicate-data

Hi I have something like this in my database -

[image]

Now I need to write a query that gives me the following result -

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use normal SQL statements in Android SQLite

```
SELECT month, day_of_week, sum(data) AS total_data, count(month)AS number_of_rows_combined 
FROM --table--
GROUP BY month, day_of_week
```

in Android you can use SQL as:

```
Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(
    "SELECT month, day_of_week, sum(data) AS total_data, count(_id)AS number_of_rowa_combined 
FROM --your table--
GROUP BY month, day_of_week",
    new String[] {}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
select month, day_of_week, sum(data), count(_id)
from table
group by month, day_of_week
```